# Creating Instances from text file data

Tags: string, file, python-3.x, instance

So i have a file which is formatted something like this:

> Name:Toby Lima 
>  DOB: 12/12/12 
>  Pay:50000
>
> Name:User Interface 
>  DOB:11/11/11
>  Pay:60000

So I basically need to read through each line and extract the relevant information and then create an Employee instance which I'll append to a list. The blank lines mark the start of a new employee. So I need to create separate instances for each employee. I'm not sure what needs to be modified in my code to achieve that.

My attempt at a solution:

```
    temp =[]

    with open(path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:

        for line in file:

            if line != '\n':
                temp.append([value for value in line.strip().split(':')[1:]])

            else: break
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the employees are separated by an empty space, you can split the data on a double new line.

```
with open(path, 'r') as o :
    data = o.read().split('\n\n')
    print(data)
    >>> ['Name:Toby Lima\nDOB: 12/12/12\nPay:50000', 'Name:User Interface\nDOB:11/11/11\nPay:60000']
```

Afterwards, you can iterate through your list and parse each employee individual. I would recommend used a `dict` to store you data to access the data easier later on

```
employees = []

#iterates through your data list
for d in data:         
    #creates a key/value pair with the employee data
    employees.append(dict([e.split(':') for e in d.split('\n')])) 

print(employees)
>>> [{'Name': 'Toby Lima', 'DOB': ' 12/12/12', 'Pay': '50000'}, {'Name': 'User Interface', 'DOB': '11/11/11', 'Pay': '60000'}]
```